# How to hide div in a re usable component in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have navbar re-usable component which contains logo, and company name, now I would like to hide the company name in one of my component where I will use this navbar, how do I accomplish that?

**Note: I am using functional component**

Here is navbar

```html
<nav className="navbar">
  <div className="container">
    <span className="navbar-brand">
      logo
    </span>
    <ul showName={true} className="nav navbar-nav">
      <li className="nav-item ">
        <a className="nav-link" href="#">Company name</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </>}
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my another component where I am using navbar and I want to hide the company name

```
<Navbar showName={false}/>
```

but this is not working, I get the following error

> Warning: React does not recognize the `showName` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `showname` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

What do I need to change to make this working ?

Comment: `Navbar` is a custom component which has `showName` prop, `ul` is not. If you want to not render it in some condition - https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use what we call conditionnal rendering, there are at least 5 ways of doing it, one of them is:

Call your navbar like you did

```
<Navbar showName={false}/>
```

Then use this props in your component like this :

```
<nav className="navbar">
    <div className="container">
         <span className="navbar-brand">
             logo
         </span>

         { 
             props.showName && 
                 <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                     <li className="nav-item ">
                         <a className="nav-link" href="#">Company name</a>
                     </li>
                 </ul> 
         }
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is an an article with other ways of doing it : (even if in this usecase it's probably the best ...)
https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-ways-to-implement-conditional-rendering-in-react-64730323b434

Answer (score 0):

You are making mistake here,

```
<ul showName={true} className="nav navbar-nav">
```

Here `showName={true}` gets directly add in DOM. It not React Component. Thus React Assusmes your making mistake (Which you are)

You might want to add extra css class/style directly like this,

```
<ul className={`nav navbar-nav ${ showName ? 'hide-it' : '' }`}>
<ul style={{ display: 'none' }} className="nav navbar-nav">
```